# Why "-static" flag is required on some machines and forbidden on another ones?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm facing a strange problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I develop a code which is able to download and install third-party libraries, thanks to the ExternalProject_Add function of CMake. I compile my code with GCC 4.9.2 and everything works fine. Here are the flags I use :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -fopenmp -lgfortran -Wno-deprecated")
```

On another machine (same Ubuntu 12.04 system), it does not work with GCC 5: I get some undefined references with a 3rd-party library (cppunit). The error messages are written in French (I'm sorry for that). For example, I get

> test_simol.cpp:(.text+0x49): référence indéfinie vers « CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) »

I found a way to solve the problem: add "-static" to gcc flags. However, if I do that, I get an error message on the first machine.

Could someone explain me what's happening here and how to solve the problem with a solution working on all machines? I'm not sure to understand the role played by "-static" flag here.

Note: the problem may come from GCC but I can't predict which version of GCC will be used by users.

Thanks!

EDIT: add -std=c++11 flag

Comment: are the third party libraries precompiled?

Comment: Just to get this out of the way; are you using any feature from C++11? The error makes it look like gcc5 / cppunit is trying to use `cxx11`. If so make sure you add the flag `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: Yes, I use the flag -std=c++11. Sorry, I forgot to mention it. The libraries are not precompiled: they are downloaded, compiled and installed with CMake, when I type 'make' for my code (automatic installation).

Comment: The definition of `std::string` changed in libstdc++ with GCC release 5. This was required because the old reference-counted string class was not C++11 compliant.

Comment: why not use the same gcc version on different machines?

Comment: Sure, it will be simpler to tell everyone to use the same compiler but I can't in practice. The other machine is a user's machine.

Comment: (I think if you say something like `LANG= make` you might be able to get normal error messages back.)

Comment: @5gon12eder: Good point; there might be a macro you can set to get the old string definition.

Comment: The problem of std::string may be the origin of my problem. Maybe, the wrong stdlibc++ is used here. Do you know how to check it?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, it is `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI`. Maybe tinkering with it could help get rid of the linker error.

Comment: I'm trying this solution to see what happens